# Переименование архива ZIP после открытия

Tags: python, zipfile

Моя задача получить список архивов в директории, пробежаться по каждому архиву, открыть его, заглянуть в лежащие внутри xml файлы, вытащить некоторые тэги из них и в соответствии с этими тэгами переименовать сам архив.

Вот что я наработал на скорую руку:

```
import os
import zipfile

from lxml import etree

folder = r"D:/Переименование массивов/"
file = r".xml"

list_zip = [os.path.join(folder, _) for _ in os.listdir(folder)]


def main():
    for zip_file in list_zip:
        list_tags = []
        try:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zf:
                for name in zf.namelist():
                    if name.endswith(file):
                        xml_file = zf.open(name, 'r')
                        tree = etree.parse(xml_file)
                        tags = tree.xpath('*//ПоПодразделению|*//ТипДокумента')
                        for tag in tags:
                            tuple_tags = tag.tag, tag.text
                            list_tags.append(tuple_tags)
            return rename_zip(list_tags, zip_file)

        except zipfile.BadZipfile as error:
            print(error)


def rename_zip(list_tags, zip_file):
    if list_tags[0] == list_tags[2] and list_tags[3][1] == 'Вариант_1':
        print('Массив 1!')
        os.rename(zip_file, 'Вариант_1.zip')
    if list_tags[0] == list_tags[2] and list_tags[3][1] == 'Вариант_2':
        print('Массив 2!')
        os.rename(zip_file, 'Вариант_2.zip')
    return print(zip_file)


print(main())
```

Выдает ошибку:

> PermissionError: `[WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом: 'D:/Переименование массивов/zipSEDfiles6258.zip' -> 'Вариант_1.zip'`

Если же я добавляю `zf.close()` в функцию `main` то пишет что ZIP файл уже закрыт.

Comment: Пробуйте указывать полный путь вторым параметром при переименовании

Comment: Сложно сказать, может ваш антивирус интересуется, что за архивы вы открываете и архивы лочатся антивирусом, пока он их проверяет. Я бы попробовал поставить задержку какую-то перед переименованием. Или собрать все имена и переименования в список, потом задержка, а потом пройтись по этому списку и переименовать. И да, у вас что - всего два названия, в которые вы архивы будете переименовывать? А самих архивов при этом сколько? Они же пересекаться будут и затираться, если их больше, чем 2.

Comment: Попробовал полный путь: `os.rename(zip_file, f'{folder}Вариант_1.zip')`
Результат тот же.
Архивов будет много но в их названии будет присутствовать уникальный номер, взятый из XML лежащих внутри. Вот этот тэг `*//ПоПодразделению` Поэтому пересекаться они не будут. Просто для тестирования что логика работает использую всего 2 архива.
Теория с антивирусом интересная. Попробую дома запустить, может ограничения на рабочем компе стоят. Всем спасибо, но если будут еще идеи, буду рад.

Comment: может просто не успевает закрыть архив? Кстати, строчка ``return rename_zip(list_tags, zip_file)`` с учетом того, что именно возвращает ``rename_zip()`` - ерунда. Да и ``return print(zip_file)`` тоже ерунда.

Comment: Да, понимаю что ерунда, код сырой, пытаюсь просто его заставить работать.
Если добавляю `zf.close()` перед return
то ошибка меняется:
`ValueError: Attempt to use ZIP archive that was already closed`
То есть архив все же закрывается

Answer (score 0):

Все проблему решил. Всем спасибо. Я закрывал не тот файл

```
def main():
    for zip_file in list_zip:
        list_tags = []
        try:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zf:
                for name in zf.namelist():
                    if name.endswith(file):
                        xml_file = zf.open(name, 'r')
                        tree = etree.parse(xml_file)
                        tags = tree.xpath('*//ПоПодразделению|*//ТипДокумента')
                        for tag in tags:
                            tuple_tags = tag.tag, tag.text
                            list_tags.append(tuple_tags)
                        xml_file.close()
            return rename_zip(list_tags, zip_file)

        except zipfile.BadZipfile as error:
            print(error)
```

Вот так должно быть.
**xml_file.close()**

Буду работать дальше.

Comment: Тогда уж лучше `with zf.open(name, 'r') as xml_file` вместо `xml_file = zf.open(name, 'r')` и `xml_file.close()`

Comment: Понял, спасибо.